# ZKSync is not a constructor

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write test using a class , but I am getting an error.

Here is the test:

```
import assert from 'assert'
const  ethers  = require('ethers');
const zksync = require('zksync');

const ZKSync = require('../../../../app/scripts/controllers/zksync');


describe('zkSync', function () {
    let zkSync
    before(async () => {
        // zkSync = new ZKSync(new Proxy({}, ethers, zksync))
        zkSync = new ZKSync(ethers, zksync);
    })
  
    describe('initAccount', function () {
      it('registers an account on zksync', async () => {
        const TEST_SEED = 'debris dizzy just program just float decrease vacant alarm reduce speak stadium'
        const ethersProvider = await  new ZKSync.getEthereumProvider(ethers,'rinkeby')
        const zkSyncProvider = await new  ZKSync.getZkSyncProvider('testnet');
        const aliceRinkebyWallet = new  ethersProvider.Wallet.fromMnemonic(TEST_SEED);
        const aliceZKsyncWallet = new ZKSync.initAccount(aliceRinkebyWallet,zkSyncProvider); 

        assert.strictEqual(await aliceZKsyncWallet.isSigningKeySet(), true, 'account is registered.')
      })
    })
})
```

Here is the code it calls:

```
const ethers = require('ethers')
const zksync = require('zksync')

export default class ZKSync {
  constructor (ethers, zksync) {
    // const initState = opts.initState || {}
    // this.store = new ObservableStore(initState)
    // this.keyringController = opts.keyringController
    this.ethers = ethers
    this.zksync = zksync
  }
  
  async getZkSyncProvider (zksync, networkName) {
    let zkSyncProvider
    try {
      zkSyncProvider = await zksync.getDefaultProvider(networkName)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to zkSync.')
      console.log(error)
    }
    return zkSyncProvider
  }
  
  async  getEthereumProvider (ethers, networkName) {
    let ethersProvider
    try {
      // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
      ethersProvider = new this.ethers.getDefaultProvider(networkName)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Could not connect to Rinkeby')
      console.log(error)
    }
    return ethersProvider
  }
  async  initAccount (rinkebyWallet, zkSyncProvider) {
    const zkSyncWallet = await this.zksync.Wallet.fromEthSigner(rinkebyWallet, zkSyncProvider)
    return zkSyncWallet
  }
}
```

I run the tests with `mocha test/unit/app/controllers/zksync-lib-test.js`.

However , I get the following error:

```
  TypeError: ZKSync is not a constructor
```

I will appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: `new ZKSync.getEthereumProvider(ethers,'rinkeby')`? What are you trying to do here? I'm also not seeing where you use `zkSync`.

Comment: it is part of the library I will update it.

Comment: Yes, but are you intending on creating a new object each time? And which line is the error on?

Comment: Yes I intend on creating a new object.  The error comes from `zkSync = new ZKSync(ethers, zksync);`